# Flink Statefun connections to Flink Table API

Tags: apache-flink, flink-statefun

We are interested in connecting to a regular Flink Streaming application from [new Stateful Functions](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-statefun-docs-release-2.0/) , ideally using the Table API.  The idea is to consult tables registered in Flink from Statefun, **is this possible, and what is the right way to do it?**

My idea so far has been to initialize my table stream in some main function and register a stateful function provider to connect to the table:

```java
@AutoService(StatefulFunctionModule.class)
public class Module implements StatefulFunctionModule {

  @Override
  public void configure(Map<String, String> globalConfiguration, Binder binder) {
    StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
    StreamTableEnvironment tableEnv = StreamTableEnvironment.create(env);

    // ingest a DataStream from an external source
    DataStream<Tuple3<Long, String, Integer>> ds = env.addSource(...);

    // SQL query with an inlined (unregistered) table
    Table myTable = tableEnv.fromDataStream(ds, "user, product, amount");
    tableEnv.createTemporaryView("my_table", myTable);

    TableFunctionProvider tableProvider = new TableFunctionProvider();
    binder.bindFunctionProvider(FnEnrichmentCallback.TYPE, tableProvider);

    //continue registering my other messages
    //...
  }
}
```

The stateful function provider would return a `FnTableQuery` which simply queries the table whenever it receives a message:

```java
public class TableFunctionProvider implements StatefulFunctionProvider {

  @Override
  public StatefulFunction functionOfType(FunctionType type) {
    return new FnTableQuery();
  }
}
```

The query function object would then operate as an actor for every established process, and simply query the table when invoked:

```java
public class FnTableQuery extends StatefulMatchFunction {

  static final FunctionType TYPE = new FunctionType(Identifiers.NAMESPACE, "my-table");

  private Table myTable;

  @Override
  public void configure(MatchBinder binder) {
    StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
    StreamTableEnvironment tableEnv = StreamTableEnvironment.create(env);

    myTable = tableEnv.from("my_table");

    binder
        .otherwise(this::catchAll);
  }

  private void catchAll(Context context, Object message) {
    context.send(FnEnrichmentCallback.TYPE, myTable.select("max(amount)").toString(), message);
  }
}
```

I apologize in advance if this approach doesn't make sense, because I don't know if:

1. Flink and Statefun applications can work together outside the realm of sources/sinks, especially since this particular function is stateless and the table is stateful
2. We can query Flink tables like this, I have only queried them as an intermediate object to send to a sink or datastream
3. It makes sense to initialize things in Module.configure, and if both the stateful function provider and its match function are [called once per parallel worker](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-statefun-docs-release-2.0/sdk/java.html#function-providers-and-dependency-injection)

Answer (score 0):

The Apache Flink community does have in mind to support Flink DataStreams as StateFun ingress / egresses in the future.

What this would mean is that you can take the result streams of using the Flink Table API / Flink CEP / DataStream API etc., and invoke functions using the events in the streams.